# Get list of all files from Last Sunday to this Sunday and between specific time frame

Tags: linux, shell-script

Get list of all files from Last Sunday to this Sunday and between specific time frame. Let today be Sunday. I need list of all files from last Sunday 12pm to this Sunday 10am. Could some one help please.

Comment: What criteria will you use for identifying these files? Create date? Change date? etc
Which file system?

Comment: The modified date is being used to identify files. Unix file system.(.TXT files)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to indicate what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid getting solutions that you already know won't work.

Comment: Where are the files?  Are you searching an entire filesystem?  A single directory?  A sub-tree?  Please edit to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

check out `man find`
and `man touch`
You can use the touch command to create an empty file named 'start' with a creation timestamp of last Sunday:

```
touch -d"October 24 2021 00:00:00" start
```

Then do the same thing with your end date call that file end.
Then ls -lat should show those files having your date ranges.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user group       0 Oct 24 00:00 start
```

last you run the find command:

```
find . -newer start ! -newer end
```